# Getting InvalidOperationException while calling GetOwner

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query

In the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string javaProcWql = string.Format("SELECT ProcessId, Name, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{0}' AND CommandLine LIKE '%{1}%'", "firefox.exe", "firefox");
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(javaProcWql);
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mo["ProcessId"]);
                string[] userinfo = new string[2];
                mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])userinfo);
                Console.WriteLine("ha ha --> " + userinfo[1] + "\\" + userinfo[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get `InvalidOperationException` and the message along with exception is

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have an InnerException?

Comment: No, there is no InnerException.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. The query should be like:

```
string.format( "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{0}' AND CommandLine LIKE '%{1}%'", "firefox.exe", "firefox" )
```

My explanation is a guess as I am not an expert in programming on Windows or .NET . In original query (see question) I was selecting fields, but by specifying `*` I select the objects, so I can call the methods on them.

Answer (score 3):

GetOwner method need to Handle field.

add Handle field to select statment:

```
SELECT Handle, ProcessId, Name, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process where ...
```